# How to make a preallocated array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make this for loop pre allocated in matlab. I am having trouble transferring data from one array to another. Can someone help make this preallocated array

```
myArray = [] 
variableArray= []

 for i=1:10
 variable = [1,2,3]
 variableArray = [variable]
 myArray = [myArray variableArray]

end
```

Comment: Your second line does nothing, `variable ` and `variableArray` are always the same.

Answer (score 1):

As @Daniel mentionned in comments, the second line

```
variableArray = [variable];
```

does nothing at all and can be dumped.

What you do in the for loop is concatenate 10 vectors of size `1x3`. The resulting vector will therefore be `1x30`. This can be verified by getting the size after running your code:

```
size(myArray)
ans = 
    1 30
```

To preallocate this vector, you can create a vector of zeros which has this size:

```
myArray = zeros(1,30);
```

You can then chose to either iterate through from `1` to `30` in steps of `3`, as suggested by @Santhan Salai in his answer, or go from `1` to `10` as before and use logical indexing to write the `variable` to the correct place, like I am demonstrating in the following snippet:

```
myArray = zeros(1,30);
for k=1:10
    variable = [1,2,3];
    myArray(3*(k-1)+1:3*k) = variable;
end
```

Note that I changed the loop variable from `i` to `k`, as `i` is used as the imaginary unit in MATLAB and should not be used as variable (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab) for details).

You can actually also dump the for loop and do this with the [`repmat`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) function, which needs no loop and no preallocation:

```
myArray = repmat([1,2,3],1,10);
```

which replicates the vector `[1,2,3]` 10 times.

Comment: Your preallocation code snippet is not preallocating, you're still growing the array in size by concatenating `variable` onto the end of it in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @excaza Oh you are right of course, I had completely overlooked that. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by **excaza** as a comment in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29589343/2111163), here is the Modified `for` loop with pre-allocation

```
myArray = zeros(1,30);
for i=1:3:30
    variable = [1,2,3];
    myArray(i:i+2) = variable;
end
```

Else, you could use the [vectorization](/questions/tagged/vectorization) approach with `repmat` as suggested by **hbaderts** in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29589343/2111163)